# Unable to decrypt event publishers in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 6.0 and in the server startup, I can see the following errors.

```
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:17,209] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} - Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-OauthTokenIssueRefresh
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:17,215] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} - Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-OauthTokenRevocation
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:17,218] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} - Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-OauthTokenValidation
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:17,225] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} - Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-AuthenticationData-1.1.0
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:17,228] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} - Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-RoleData
TID: [] [] [2023-06-08 10:03:17,234] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.util.EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder} - Unable to decrypt the encrypted field: password in adaptor: IsAnalytics-Publisher-wso2event-UserData
...
```

What are the steps I can take to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when WSO2 IS cannot decrypt the password property you have defined and encrypted in the event publishers.
To fix this, go to `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers` and open the respective `.xml` files. If they have something like this,

```
<property encrypted="true" name="password">{ENCRYPTED_VALUE}</property>
```

You have to change it to the following and restart the server.

```
<property encrypted="false" name="password">{ADMIN_PASSWORD}</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event publisher, we have the password property encrypted by default. Therefore during event adaptor deployment, it tries to decrypt the password using the OSGI service CryptoService. If the IS analytics event publishers' OSGi service is got deployed before the deployment of cryptoService OSGi Service, then you can see this error.

This can happen when stopping the server if the OSGI bundle that registers the CryptoService is undeployed before the event publishers, then from the EventPublisherConfigurationBuilder above error log will be printed.

The root cause of this issue lies in this [line](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.7.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/internal/CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java#L164), where cardinality is optional, not mandatory.

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76445158/7765194) is a workaround, where we state that the property is not encrypted so IS Analytics service doesn't need to call CryptoService.